# TextView blocking bottom navigation

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm having an issue in the Android app that I'm developing where a the text in a Fragment containing a `TextView` covers the bottom navigation if the text is too long. The issue looks like this:

`TextView` blocking bottom navigation

[image]

Here's the code for the Fragment:

```
package com.example.xxxxxx.loremipsum;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 * Activities that contain this fragment must implement the
 * {@link LessonFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener} interface
 * to handle interaction events.
 * Use the {@link LessonFragment#newInstance} factory method to
 * create an instance of this fragment.
 */
public class LessonFragment extends Fragment
{
    private String lessonContent;
    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;
    TextView lesson;
    private int lessonID;
    private boolean culture;
    public LessonFragment()
    {

    }

    @SuppressLint("ValidFragment")
    public LessonFragment(int lessonID)
    {
        this.lessonID = lessonID;
        culture = false;
    }

    @SuppressLint("ValidFragment")
    public LessonFragment(int lessonID, int i)
    {
        this.lessonID = lessonID;
        culture = true;
    }

    /**
     * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
     * this fragment using the provided parameters.
     *
     * @param param1 Parameter 1.
     * @param param2 Parameter 2.
     * @return A new instance of fragment LessonFragment.
     */
    public static LessonFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2)
    {
      return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null)
        {

        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_lesson, container, false);
        ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        view.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        Button button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.backButton);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view)
            {
                if(!culture)
                {
                    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
                    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                    GrammarFragment GF = new GrammarFragment();
                    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, GF);
                    fragmentTransaction.commit();
                }
                else
                {
                    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
                    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                    CultureFragment CF = new CultureFragment();
                    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, CF);
                    fragmentTransaction.commit();
                }
            }
        });
        lesson = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.grammarContent);
        String[] lessons;
        if(!culture)
             lessons = getActivity().getResources().getStringArray(R.array.lessons);
        else
             lessons = getActivity().getResources().getStringArray(R.array.cultureLessons);
        lessonContent = lessons[lessonID];
        lesson.setText(lessonContent);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context)
    {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener)
        {
            mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                    + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach()
    {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }


    /**
     * This interface must be implemented by activities that contain this
     * fragment to allow an interaction in this fragment to be communicated
     * to the activity and potentially other fragments contained in that
     * activity.
     * <p>
     * See the Android Training lesson <a href=
     * "http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html"
     * >Communicating with Other Fragments</a> for more information.
     */
    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener
    {
        void onBackClickCulture();
    }


}
```

Here's the XML for the Fragment:

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
tools:context="com.example.xxxxxx.loremipsum.LessonFragment">

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/grammarContent"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Back"
            android:id="@+id/backButton"
            tools:ignore="OnClick" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Finally, here's the XML for my MainActivity, where the Fragment is being added:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.xxxxxx.loremipsum.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

EDIT: Here's a screenshot of a further issue:

Here's the bug I'm having

[image]

Comment: May be you should consider arranging a hierarchy this way. A parent containing 2 children., A fragment container and bottom bar. Fragment container above bottom bar.

Comment: @mnp343 thanks for the idea, i added another nested constraint layout and added the fragment to that, and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Please add one more layout in your `MainActivity` xml portion. And you also change in `MainActivity` `R.id.fl_main` with `R.id.container`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.buttonnavifragment.MainActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fl_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: I tried this, but all the fragments just ended up covering each other.

Comment: share screenshot

Comment: share screenshot after using FrameLayout

Comment: that is the screenshot using FrameLayout

Comment: MainActivity is identical, except for the container you told me to change

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

- Your container should be an View which should be above `BottomNavigationView`. That's why you are having these conflicts. Because you just attach Fragment on parent view.
- Set a background always to `Fragment` parent element. Because Fragment inflate on top of other to maintain stack.